# Moving files to a folder if the folder name contains a part of the file name?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm working on a script to copy files from a source directory to individual folders that share a 10 digit string within the file and folder name. The file and folder names are not the same, but they both will contain 10 digits that I'm trying to match with. The `$num_list` contains a list of phone numbers that are also located somewhere within the file name.
example:

```
1234567890
1234567891
1234567892
```

My goal is to copy files from my source directory that looks something like this `Inbound_1234567890.mp3` and copy them into folders within my destination directory that are named like `Person 1234567890`

Here is my current script:

```
#set source and destination directory
$source = "D:\testInput\Ring\Archiver"
$destination = "D:\testOutput\Clients"

#creates .txt with all folder names
Get-ChildItem $destination | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } > $destination\num_list.txt
#removes everything but the phone number
(Get-Content $destination\num_list.txt) -replace '\D','' | Set-Content $destination\num_list.txt

#list of numbers generated from destination 
$num_list = Get-Content "$destination\num_list.txt"

#for each number in num_list
foreach ($num in $num_list){
    #for each file in the ring archive
    foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *.mp3 -Recurse)){
        #if the file name is in the directory
        if($num -match '\d{10}'){
            Copy-Item $file.Fullname -Destination $destination -Verbose
        }
}
}
```

My output ends up copying the files to the destination, which is correct based on the script, but I can't figure out how to target each folder that has the phone number in the folder name. I tried creating a new directory with a wildcard to specify the path, but that syntax doesn't work properly

```
        if($num -match '\d{10}'){
            $folder_name = $matches[0]
            $new_dest = $destination\*$folder_name*
            Copy-Item $file.Fullname -Destination $new_dest -Verbose
```

Is there a way to target each individual folder based on phone number only?

Thanks for the help!

**Update:**
I've tried a different approach but i keep getting that the target recording path is null. I'm also choosing to try to match the regex by the numbers in the txt file since the mp3 file contains other 10 digit combinations to look through.  Any recommendations on improving this logic? I know i'm so close but yet so far.

```
#set source and destination directory
$source = "D:\testInput\Ring\Archiver"
$destination = "D:\testOutput\Clients"

Get-ChildItem $destination | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } > $destination\num_list.txt
(Get-Content $destination\num_list.txt) -replace '\D','' | Set-Content $destination\num_list.txt

#list of client phone numbers generated from the client folder
$num_list = Get-Content "$destination\num_list.txt"

#for each file in the ring archive
(Get-ChildItem $source -File -Filter *.mp3 -Recurse) |
ForEach-Object {$recordings}

(Get-ChildItem $destination -Directory -Recurse) |
ForEach-Object {$clients}

#for each of the numbers in num_list
foreach ($num in $num_list) {
        #match number to the same number in a file name
        ($recordings -match $num)
        $target_recording = $Matches[0]
        if ($target_recording -Match ([regex]::Matches($clients,'$num').Value)) {
                Copy-Item -Path $target_recording.FullName -Destination $clients -Whatif 
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you need to find all mp3 files in a folder recursively that have a 10 digit phone number in their name.
If such a number corresponds to one of the client folder names you keep in destination path, the file should be copied there.

For that, I would use a lookup hashtable where the Keys represent the phonenumbers of existing client folders and the Values store the client folders full path.

```
$source      = "D:\testInput\Ring\Archiver"
$destination = "D:\testOutput\Clients"

# create a lookup hashtable for all existing client folders
# the Key is the 10 digit phonenumber, the Value is the folders full path
$clientHash = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '(\d{10})' } | ForEach-Object {
    $clientHash[$matches[1]] = $_.FullName
}

# go through the files in the sourcefolder and copy all mp3 files with a matching phonenumber to the destination
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter '*.mp3' -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '(\d{10})' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # for better readability store the phonenumber in the file in a variable
        $number = $matches[1]
        if ($clientHash.ContainsKey($number)) {
            # we have a client folder with that number
            Write-Host "Copying file $($_.Fullname) to client folder '$($clientHash[$number])'"
            Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination $clientHash[$number] -WhatIf
        }
        else {
            # unknown number
            Write-Warning "Cannot copy file $($_.Fullname).. No client found for phone number $number"
        }
    }
```

The `-WhatIf` safety switch ensures no copying is done and only info lines appear in the console showing what *would* happen. If you are satisfied this is all OK, remove the `-WhatIf` switch and run again.

Of course, if you'd rather move the files than copying them, change `Copy-Item` into `Move-Item`

Comment: this makes so much more sense and easier than the route I was trying to take, thank you this helped a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
'Folder1234567890Text',
'Folder1234567891PDF',
'Folder1234567892XLS' | 
ForEach-Object {New-Item -Path 'D:\Temp' -Name $PSItem -ItemType Directory}

'Folder1234567890Text.txt',
'Folder1234567891PDF.pdf',
'Folder1234567892XLS.xls' | 
ForEach-Object {New-Item -Path 'D:\Temp' -Name $PSItem -ItemType File}


(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File) -match '\d{10}'
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                       
-a----         06-Feb-20     14:02          28817 23694d1213305764-revision-number-in-excel-book1.xls                                                        
-a----         04-Dec-20     17:31              0 Folder1234567890Text.txt                                                                                   
-a----         04-Dec-20     17:31              0 Folder1234567891PDF.pdf                                                                                    
-a----         04-Dec-20     17:31              0 Folder1234567892XLS.xls 
#>

(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Directory) -match '\d{10}' | 
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Verbose -Message "Processing $(($TargetFolderName = $PSItem.FullName))" -Verbose

    (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File) -match '\d{10}' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        If ($PSItem.Name -Match ([regex]::Matches($TargetFolderName,'\d{10}').Value))
        {Move-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination $TargetFolderName -WhatIf}
    }
}
# Results
<#
VERBOSE: Processing D:\Temp\Folder1234567890Text
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Folder1234567890Text.txt Destination: D:\Temp\Folder1234567890Text\Folder1234567890Text.txt".
VERBOSE: Processing D:\Temp\Folder1234567891PDF
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Folder1234567891PDF.pdf Destination: D:\Temp\Folder1234567891PDF\Folder1234567891PDF.pdf".
VERBOSE: Processing D:\Temp\Folder1234567892XLS
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Folder1234567892XLS.xls Destination: D:\Temp\Folder1234567892XLS\Folder1234567892XLS.xls".
#>
```

***Update as per your comment below***
No reason to hardcode directory names.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Recurse) -match '\d{10}' | 
ForEach-Object {$PSItem}
```

Comment: I think that helps a little bit... though what's confusing me is how I would set a TargetFolderName. There are hundreds of folders and not something I would want to hard code into the script.

Comment: No worries. There is no need to hard code directories.

Comment: Sorry I'm having a difficult time trying to incorporate your script into mine... Does it matter at all that my target folder isn't exactly like the file name that i'm trying to move? Also the source and destinations are in completely different directories. I also realized that the text file I'm reading in actually isn't doing anything in the nested loop. Perhaps the better way to go about this would be to compare each file with the 10 digits and find the folder with the same 10 digits and if that condition is met, copy the file over to that specified folder?

Comment: I just use the same name in my example to keep things easy to follow. The code does not evaluate or care what string is to the left or right of the regex match. It just reads in the folders, look for files in the directory and move them by the regex match. file source and destination can be whatever you choose.

Comment: Hi I updated the post with something I've been trying, do you have any recommendations on how I can fix my logic about this?